# Why only the two choices in blood?

Tags: morbius

In Morbius Michael and Lucious have blood born diseases and as a result Michael tries to develop a cure. He first comes up with synthetic blood.

> Then he tries to come up with a cure but it's a horrible mistake, making him into a vampire. Once he's a vampire he initially has 6 hours, which reduces to 4, to sate his hunger with synthetic blood. The alternative is human blood.
>
>  But why not animal blood? It seems as though that would be a better solution but it's not even explored in Morbius.  Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3):

The entire notion of Vampirism is based in horror folklore.  To borrow from the [Wiki on Vampires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire):

> In most cases, vampires are revenants of evil beings, suicide victims,
> or witches, but they can also be created by a malevolent spirit
> possessing a corpse or by being bitten by a vampire.

There's nothing very scary about a being that feasts on animal blood.  What would I care?  They're not looking for *me*.  But if that being is looking for *human* blood, then that means I might become a victim.  That thought of being on their food chain is what makes it scary.